# gt table conditional styling also subtotals

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to generate a table with the gt package in R. So far so good... But I would like also that my conditional styling also applies to the summary (subtotal per group).
Is there any way to make it with the gt package.

Edit:

```
data <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A"), Region = c("Bbbb", "Cccc"), 
    `Ytd Supply` = c(11867.67, 1557.87), `Ytd Budget` = c(11364.25, 
    1352.97), `Ytd Dif` = c(-503.42, -204.9), `Ytg Supply` = c(8432.97, 
    10313.95), `Ytg Budget` = c(8945.33, 10777.04), `Ytg Dif` = c(-512.360000000001, 
    -463.089999999998)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(
    Type = "A", .rows = structure(list(1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))




gt(data) %>%
  tab_header(
  title = "my tytle") %>%
tab_spanner(
  label = "YTD",
  columns = contains("YTD")) %>%  
tab_spanner(
  label = "YTG",
  columns = contains("YTG")) %>%
summary_rows(
  groups = TRUE,
  columns = where(is.numeric),
    fns = list(
       Total = ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
 tab_style(
    style = list(
    cell_fill(color = "#F08080")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = `Ytd Dif`,
      rows =  `Ytd Dif` < 0))
```

Thanks

Comment: In this case some example data would be really helpful. `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: @TarJae thanks. Totally right. Never used dput() before. Hope my edit is correct.
Thanks

Comment: You can format summary rows within the tab_options(). tab_options(summary_row.background.color = "#F08080")